# Django model validation

Tags: django, forms, validation, model

I'm facing a validation problem.
I need to use form validation and model validation together, but django (1.10) doesn't seem to like this.

Here is a short version of my setup:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey('ap.Model')
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def clean(self):
        if self.fk.som_field != self.foo:
            raise ValidationError("This did not validate")

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('fk',)

def view(request):
    instance = MyModel(foo='bar')
    form = MyModelForm(data=request.POST, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        # process
        # redirect
    # display template
```

So I have some model field validation in the model itself.
I need this here because it is re-used in other non-form related parts of my application.

And I have some user input validation in the form.
In this case, checking that the provided fk is valid and exists.

But when the form is validated and the user provided 'fk' is not valid, the form is rejected.
But the form also calls MyModel.full_clean add more model validation.

The problem is that calling MyModel.clean() without having any data in the field *fk* will raise a RelatedObjectDoesNotExist exception.

How can I do this the proper way ?
I feel that MyModel.full_clean() should not be called by the form until the form itself is valid to ensure that the model is validated with at least correct field types in it.

I could embed my MyModel.clean operations in a try/except that would catch a RealtedObjectDoesNotExist, but it has a bad code smell for me.
The fact that MyModel.fk exists should be ensured by the first form layer validation.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, the model form performs the instance validation (by calling self.instance.full_clean()`) whether or not the form is valid.

You could prevent this behaviour (I might try to override the [`_post_clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/forms/models.py#L371), but I think it's simpler to take account of the behaviour in the `clean` method.

Rather than catching the exception, it would be simpler to check that `self.fk_id` is not None before accessing `self.fk`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey('ap.Model')
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def clean(self):
        if self.fk_id is not None and self.fk.som_field != self.foo:
            raise ValidationError("This did not validate")
```